# How to use data from db i get with php in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I have stored links to the images in my database, links being to my hard drive and not http kind of links. I managed to get all that data using php and i want to show all the photos that are linked in my JavaScript carousel, but I have no clue how to use data I got with php in JavaScript. I got data with php using code:

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("TEMP");
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tv ORDER BY id ASC");

    $id = 'id';

    $path = 'path';

    while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        echo 'Adresas: ' . $rows[$path] . '</br>';
    }
```

I have a JavaScript carousel that looks like this:

```
<div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:500px">
  <img class="mySlides" src="images/Chrysanthemum.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="images/Desert.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="images/Hydrangeas.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="images/Jellyfish.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="images/Koala.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>


<script>
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 5000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
</script>
```

As you can see it uses images from div that are hard coded, instead i would like to use links i got from my database. How should I do that?

Comment: [AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/).

Comment: Don't use the insecure and deprecated `mysql_*` functions. Use Mysqli or PDO instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all browser won't load any content over file:// protocol if your HTML document has been loaded over http(s):// protocol. The reason is sequrity (not sure if you'd like to let any webpage reading your local disk content, right?).

When browser requests your page, PHP is being executed on server side and generates the content your browser gets as response. This content may contain javascript as well, and it will be executed in browser when it receives the responce. I common, the simplest PHP page you need could look like this:

```
<?php
    // we'll store the list here
    $urls = [];

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Execute the query
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT path FROM tv ORDER BY id ASC");
    // Fetch all selected rows one by one
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $urls[] = $row["path"];    
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
<div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:500px">
    <?php foreach ($urls as $url): ?>
        <img class="mySlides" src="<?=$url?>" style="width:100%">
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Note that this example is VERY simple. It illustrates the answer, but it contains some bad practices like mixing HTML content with server-side logics etc...

UPD: Client-server development can be a bit confusing thing for the beginners, because usually they start from local webserver and both client and server are running on the same physical hardware. Always think of client (your browser) and server (Apache, Nginx or whatever you use) as different computers connected via network (even if they are running on one computer).

Comment: For some reason it didn't like $urls = []; part and threw me some kind of error, so i tried to use $urls =""; instead and it works. As i said in other comment im really new to this and hardly know where to start, but when i get the code to use i truly try my best to read it through and to understand it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: oh by the way i assume mysqli is safer way to use than a mysql? Thank you for that part of knowledge too as i saw in other comments someone saying i should use it, but not a mention of how to do so.

Comment: `$urls=[];` is a short syntax and will fail if you have PHP older than 5.4 version. You can create an array by full syntax instead `$urls = array();`
Refer to manual for more info http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Reagrding to mysql API, the extension you used in your snippet is deprecated for several reasons. Read the manual to obtain more info on how to use mysql recommended APIs http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php My example uses mysqli. You may want to to read more about `mysqli` and `mysqli_result` classes to get inspired on how to use mysql in php.

Answer (score 0):

You can open and close php tags when you wish. Closing will output the data as if it were html and opened will execute the code as php. Something like this will populate the list for you. In this case you do not need to give javascript the php data. Instead, you need to output the html via php.

```
<div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:500px">
<?php
    $rows = getRowsFromDB();
    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
        ?><img class="mySlides" src="<?php echo $row[$path];?>" style="width:100%"><?php
    }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: When i tried to use it i got some kind of error. And about downvotes i have no clue, apparently question itself is not good for such a great group of programmers, so it's getting downvoted too

Comment: @darklup, the answer is correct. If you want a copy-paste solution which just works as is, please, update your question with phrase "I won't try to understand your answer, I will just copy your snippet and paste it into my code." Of course you will get an error, because I'm sure you don't have `getRowsFromDB()` implemented, right?

Comment: exactly that. It's not like i DON'T want to understand, it's more that i dont. I'm really not used neither to php nor js, so i have pretty much no clue what it does. I guess it give a class "mySlides" to all i get from db, so it should work in my carousel? I never said your answer is incorrect, i just have no way to check if it really is correct if I have no clue how to do so.

Comment: @darklup Well, everyone had a start point ;) Just remember to split client and server in your mind. PHP runs on server. HTML/CSS/JS etc "runs" on client. PHP generates the content (any content, not only HTML), browser on the other side of wire gets it and interprets... Good luck in understanding ))

Comment: I'm not here to write applications for people, i gave an example that shows how to output html code using php, which is what the OP was having trouble with. the DB code is trivial and if that is what he is having trouble with, then ask a separate question.

Answer (score -1):

Below code may be help u.
please put u r column name in the $row variable.

```
<?php
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
?>
<img class="mySlides" src="images/<?php echo $rows['get_a_column_name'];?>" style="width:100%">
<?php
}
?>
```